# NGRX Entity Adapter - update id

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngmodel

Could you let me know if there is any possibility to easily edit id in Entity Adapter ? I would like to be able to edit it, but also avoid duplicates.

Here is flow description:

1. My adapter looks like this:

```
   adapter = createEntityAdapter<Item>({
    selectId: (item: Item) => item.id
})
```

I am getting array of items from BE:

```
    [{id:"start",value:"my value"},{id:"start2",value:"my value2"}]
```

2. It is being changed into entity in reducer:

```
     on(Actions.loadAll, (state, action) =>
            adapter.addAll(action.items, {
                ...state
            })
        ),
```

3. Each `id` is listed as an input which is editable for user . Now I would like on each change to update proper entity and its id.

How to achieve that? ngModel and adapter.update ? Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to update an entity id, because the implementation of ngrx rely on the entity.id value.

That means you need to implement your own reducer that removes (removeOne) the entity with the old id and adds (upsertOne) the new entity with the new id.